# Вот не знаю, нужна ли эта comma, или запятая

Tags: запятые

Запятушонка нужна?

> Как бы стар-забывчив я не стал, а всё равно никогда-никогда не забуду, как в вечёр зимненький мы с Вами в парковых аллеях, вовсю заснеженных, гуляли(,) — молодые, амбициозные.

Comment: Не нужна, поскольку оборот, отделенный тире, _молодые, амбициозные_ является частью изъяснительного придаточного.